# Date range in Kibana/ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I've came across an issue and I need some help to resolve it ...

I've got a time based field called startDate which has the following mapping in elasticsearch

"Start Date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" }

I can index and filter data based on it but I was wondering now how can I show data in kibana that is only for the next 2 weeks but rather than using now+2w/w I want those 2 weeks to be from for example Monday to Monday after 2 weeks or if I could set the exact date. Every time I try to parse a query other than something with "now" it crashes ...

Answer (score 0):

For those in the same situation ..
the query requires || at the end .. such as

01-01-2015 00:00:00|| when using fixed date